# Xamarin The project file cannot be opened. .NET SDK MSBulld global.json

Tags: xamarin, msbuild, dotnet-sdk, .net-sdk

I have an old cross platform Xamarin Solution which has the problem when i try to load the cross platform project in VS19:

The project file cannot be opened. Version 7.0.304 of the .NET SDK requires at least version 17.4.0 of MSBuild. The current available version of MSBulld ls 16.11.2.50704. Change the .NET SDK specified In global.json to an older verslon that requires the MSBuild version currently available.

I fixed it by installing the .NET SDK (out of support) in the VS Installer.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by installing the .NET SDK (out of support) in the VS Installer.

[image]